# remove files then folder in excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove the files in a directory, then the directory if the answer to a user prompt is no.  Below in the `excel 2010 vba`but I am getting a syntax error on the `For` line.  Thank you :).

```
Dim Directory As String
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim i As Long
iYesNo = MsgBox("Do the patients and barcode match the setup sheet?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Select Case iYesNo
             Case vbYes
             GoTo Line2
             Case vbNo
             MsgBox ("Doesn't match! Please enter again")
             MyFolder = Directory ' delete all txt files in the folder
             MyFile = MyFolder & "*.txt"
             For i = LBound(MyFile) To UBound(MyFile)
               Kill MyFolder & MyFile(i)
             Next
               RmDir Directory  ' delete folder
             GoTo Line1
       End Select
```

The directory is set to by a variable that appears to be correct when I step-through the code.

Comment: `myfile` is just a string, not array so `i` is a string, not number. Look into `dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DIR and loop through the files:

This will list the files in a folder:

```
Sub MyFileStuff()
Dim MyFile As String, MyFolder As String
MyFolder = "N:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.*")
Do Until MyFile = ""
    MsgBox MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

You can modify this to kill the file instead of msgboxing it.